# All uses of Ellipsis in C++

Tags: c++, ellipsis

Currently, I could recollect only three uses of `...` in C++:

1. variadic functions
2. variadic templates
3. catch block

I tried different ways of googling "all uses of ellipsis in C++" but failed to find it. I am focussing on the current standard of C++.

Comment: They can be used in variadic macros also

Comment: Check the standard, that's the only reference that actually counts.

Comment: http://eel.is/c++draft/generalindex#:ellipsis

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's pretty much it, besides variadic macros mentioned in the comments. I made a grouped tree list:

- Variadic

  - Template parameter packs

    - Template parameter delcaration
    - Function parameter declaration
    - Parameter pack expansions (these can be in many contexts)

      - Plain variadic expansion (can be used in declarations)
      - Fold expressions
      - Variadic sizeof
  - C style variadic parameters
  - Variadic macros
- Catch all